# Is there a way to create a collection of identical strings in java with one statement?

Tags: java

I want to create a queue of Strings that will have many identical elements in it (I'm simulating a set of program instructions). Is there any way to create this collection all at once with a single statement?

```
myQueue.addAll(create collection of x strings);
```

Otherwise, I'll obviously have to loop x times and call `myqueue.add(String)` x times.

Just wondering if there is a one-line instead of 3-line way to do this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Collections.nCopies(int n, T o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies%28int,%20T%29) returns a `List<T>` containing `n` copies of the given object `o`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myQueue.addAll(new String[]{"str", "str", "str"});
```

Answer (score 0):

myQueue.addAll(Arrays.asList(new String[]{"str", "str", "str"}));